# Why does 'InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.' occur for ARKitFaceSubsystem?

Tags: unity

Why does 'InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.' occur for ARKitFaceSubsystem in the snippet below?

```
    var faceManager = FindObjectOfType<ARFaceManager>();
    if (faceManager != null)
    {
        m_ARKitFaceSubsystem = (ARKitFaceSubsystem)faceManager.subsystem;
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to cast to ARFaceSubsystem, not ARKitFaceSubsystem? AR Foundation and AR Kit are two different libraries.

Comment: i don't think there is an `ARFaceSubsystem` ?

Comment: the cast and snippet is taken directly from official example `ARKitBlendShapeVisualizer.cs` ... the cast works there but somehow does not work in my own script? The error only shows up at runtime. https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/blob/latest-preview/Assets/Scripts/ARKitBlendShapeVisualizer.cs